# Construction of pattern that doesn't contain binary string

Tags: regex

I was trying to write a pattern which doesn't contain binary string (let's assume `101`). I know that such expressions cannot be written using `Regular Expression` considering http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_language.

I tried writing the pattern for the above problem using `Regular Expression` though and it seems to be working.

```
\b(?!101)\w+\b
```

What I wanted to ask is that can a regular expression be written for my problem and why? And if yes, then is my regular expression correct?

Comment: 'Please also include a tag specifying the programming language or tool you are using.' (from `[regex]` tag description)

Comment: I am using an online tool http://regexpal.com/ for testing the `regex`. Though I am not employing it anywhere.

Comment: Look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/406230/regular-expression-to-match-string-not-containing-a-word

Comment: The case is not similar. Some binary strings do not support `Regular Expressions`.

Answer (score 0):

To match a whole string that doesn't contain `101`:

```
^(?!.*101).*$
```

Look-ahead are indeed an easy way to check a condition on a string through regex, but your regex will only match alphanumeric words that do not start with `101`.

Answer (score 0):

You wrote

> I know that such expressions cannot be written using Regular
>   Expression considering http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_language.

In that Wikipedia article, you seem to have missed the

> Note that the "regular expression" features provided with many
>   programming languages are augmented with features that make them
>   capable of recognizing languages that can not be expressed by the
>   formal regular expressions (as formally defined below).

The negative lookahead construct is such a feature.